# Is UriMatcher capable of matching custom http links?

Tags: android, uri, matcher

I would like to use `UriMatcher` to match custom http links.

I have following code:

```
UriMatcher mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
mUriMatcher.addURI("myLink", "http://a.b.c/?id=", 1);
mUriMatcher.addURI("myLink", "http://d.e.f/?id=", 2);
int match = mUriMatcher.match(Uri.parse("http://a.b.c/?id=123"));
```

But I always get "-1" in match result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UriMatcher matches Uris of the form:

```
scheme://<authority>/<path>
```

It ignores the query string (anything appearing after ? in the url)

You register with the matcher using:

```
mUriMatcher.addURI(authority, path, result);
```

So, in your simple example above, you can not distinguish between the same URL with or without a query string, but you can match on the domain name. Use:

```
mUriMatcher.addURI('a.b.c', '/', 1);
mUriMatcher.addURI('d.e.f', '/', 2);
```

You can use UrlQuerySanitizer within each match handler to decide whether the query things you need are present or not.

Comment: When the path is present as an instance of Uri class, `path.getQueryParameter(key)` can be used to gather specific query parameters.
`path.getQuery()` gets all the parameters as a string.